# file field tag collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm looking to create a file_field_tag with a collection of options to chose from when uploading csv's.

I'm unsure on how best to implement this, even if it's possible at all to do.

So instead of having:

```
<%= form_tag upload_path, multipart: true do %>
    <p><label><b>Upload One</b></label><%= file_field_tag :one %></p>
    <p><label><b>Upload Two</b></label><%= file_field_tag :two %></p>
    <p><label><b>Upload Three</b></label><%= file_field_tag :three %></p>
    <%= submit_tag "Import File", class: 'btn' %>
<% end %>
```

I would like Upload One, Two, Three to be in a drop down selection.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<form>
  <select id="selecter">
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
  </select>

  <input type="file" name="one" id="one" class="hide file" />
  <input type="file" name="two" id="two" class="hide file" />
  <input type="file" name="three" id="three" class="hide file" />
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$("#select").change(function(event){
   selectedValue = $(this).val();
   $(".file").addClass('hide');
   $("#" + selectedValue).removeClass('hide');
});
```

Comment: This works, as in a dropdown selection appears, but does not save the data to db.

Comment: you are supposed to write the backend to save the data seperately.  There are some gems available. https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention i am using Paperclip.